# Limit of $\sqrt{x-2}$

Tags: limits

I have in the textbook

$\lim_{x\to 2^+}\sqrt{x-2}$ and $\lim_{x\to 2^-}\sqrt{x-2}$

In mathematica both give result $0$, however the book says that the limit only exists as $x\to a^-$, left hand side. When plotting the function but also just looking at it, this makes sense but what is correct. Book or Mathematica and why?

Comment: Book. The reason being is that if $x>2$, you're taking the square root of a negative number which is bad news (for your purposes).

Comment: It looks like this question was incorrectly modified from $\sqrt{2-x}$ to $\sqrt{x-2}$.  I can't correct the mistake however, as my reputation only allows me to make edits over 10 characters.  Anyone care to do the honors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit as $x \to 2^+$ is tricky to define. I don't know if you've heard of complex numbers (like $\sqrt{-1}$), and if you haven't, then the limit from above will just be meaningless.

If you have heard of them, then we usually say that $\sqrt{-1} = i$, but we might as well choose $\sqrt{-1} = -i$, and it's this choice ("branching") which gives mathematicians a headache when you use the square root sign on negative numbers.

You see, when you do something with a number ("apply a function"), like taking the square root, or multiply it by $\pi$, or add $5.67$ or anything else, you don't want to have to choose from a number of different results, you want the answer to be unique. And most of the time it is, but not when taking the square root of a negative number (the "just choose one and be done with it" approach isn't always viable, so mathematicians do all they can to  avoid having to choose, but it's done in some cases, like the inverse trigonometric functions, or the square root of positive numbers).

However, if you do make a choice, then whichever you chose, the limit will still be $0$, and that is what Mathematica is telling you.

For $x > 2$, we have
$$
\sqrt{2-x} = \sqrt{-(x-2)} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{x-2} = \pm i \sqrt{x-2} 
$$
which tends toward $\pm i \cdot 0$ as $x \to 2^+$. Remember, $i$ is just a constant, so $\lim \left(i\cdot f(x)\right) = i\cdot \lim f(x)$. As you see, no matter which sign you put in front of the $i$, the result will be the same.

Comment: I have very very basic knowledge of complex numbers, but I still do not see how when x->2+ that it becomes zero. Could you show it a bit more mathematical? In other words could you write the function for the imaginary part?

Comment: @ALEXANDER I've added some math to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recall: If $f(c)$ exists and continuous at $c$ then $\lim_{\ x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$. Notice, $x>2$ then $\sqrt{2-x}$ does not exists in $\mathbb{R}$. Mathematica did the former and logic handles the latter, which is what the text is implying.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following graph, it is of your function $\sqrt{2 - x}$

[image: Graph]

Now, if you take a limit from $2^+$, this means you are "coming" from the right side with values which are greater than $2$ but look! The function isn't defined for such values! Thus, the limit cannot exist. Now, look at it is from left side with values less than $2$. A left hand side limit makes a lot more sense because the function *is* defined and we can approach $2$ and obtain some meaningful value. I hope that helps!